# Do I need an external flash to take sports pictures on the field at night?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, flash, off-camera-flash, hotshoe-flash, manual-flash

Do I need a external flash to take sports pictures under lights on the field at night? I'm using RAW and manual exposure.

Comment: Unfortunately, sports photography is one area of photography where expensive equipment (fast long lens, high ISO body) is hardly replaceable. There's a reason why the illumination in stadiums is so big and powerful.

Answer (score 5):

In general, no, not only do you not need it, but it won't help at all. In order to provide any meaningful amount of light more than a few feet away, you need a very, very powerful flash — much more than you can get in anything battery powered.

Unless you are right on the field — less than ten feet away from your subject — even an expensive hotshoe flash will not do much. If you're a little farther than that — twenty feet, maybe — it *could* help a little bit if you also have the ISO cranked up pretty high. But mostly, it's just a waste. Light inherently diminishes with the *square* of the distance, which means that every bit further you want to reach takes a lot more power, and there's no magic solution there, unfortunately.

Comment: So i can just use the flash on the camera or no flash at all..what do you mean more then battery powered

Comment: The flash on the camera is even less powerful, and will help even less. When you see a stadium audience and the whole thing is twinkling with flashes going off, you are seeing a whole bunch of people being silly. It won't help, and because the camera isn't smart enough to know that the flash is doing no good, it probably makes the photos _worse_.

Comment: By battery powered, I mean that theoretically an AC-powered, plug-in strobe light might be able to make a meaningful difference. But good luck getting that into the stands — not to mention a very long extension cord.

Comment: I have a sb600 external flash..should i be using that. I know i shouldnt use the flash on the camera...but im not sure if i should/bave to use the sb to get good pictures

Comment: Kids youth game...not the real fancy stuff needed.just want clear images.do you know the best way to achieve that using what i have..

Comment: I don't think you're getting it. Flash is only useful for subjects at reasonably close range. The distances at which you are taking photos of field sports is too great; flash is not effective at these distances. To obtain good exposure, use large apertures and high ISO values. And leave the flash at home.

Comment: Since you already have a flash, if you still don't believe me, try it! Take a few pictures with and without and compare the difference.

Comment: Unless the sport is chess. **NO you do not need it**. You need fast iso and high lens aperture. Read carefully the answer and comments.